# Calling the new operator with two arguments but without assignment

Tags: c++, new-operator

I found this code and I don't understand, why it works in the project. The structure of the code is:

```
class MyClass {
    int value;
};

struct MyStruct {
    MyClass classA;
    MyClass classB;
};

int main() {

    MyStruct myStruct;

    new (&((&myStruct)->classA)) MyClass();
    new (&((&myStruct)->classB)) MyClass();
}
```

(The inner ampersand was added by me to create a smaller example. In the source myStruct is a pointer).

The compiler says

```
In function int main()
error: no matching function for call to ‘operator new(sizetype, MyClass*)’
    new (&((&myStruct)->classA)) MyClass();
                                         ^
note: candidates are:
note: void* operator new(long unsigned int)
note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
```

Maybe I'm missing something important. It's a big project and I can't copy it. I'm not able to create a MWE. I hope someone can explain to me the main idea behind this code and what I have to change to compile it.

Comment: Lookup [_placement `new`_](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new).

Comment: it's creating a new instance of the class `MyClass` in the two `MyClass` variables the instance `myStruct` of the struct `MyStruct` contains

Comment: This `(&myStruct)->` makes no sense. Or at least I hope it doesn't.

Comment: Can you explain, why I can't compile my example?

Comment: @ThomasSablik Which specific errors do you get?

Comment: Whomever wrote this code knows enough C++ to be dangerous, but not enough to be effective with it.

Comment: I'm curious on how someone would know about placement new, which is a rarely used feature; but not know anything about how objects are created.

Comment: I added the error message

Comment: Seems to compile if I add `#include <new>`.

Comment: Ok with `#include <new>` it works. Now I understand and my MWE can be compiled. When someone posts a full answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Placement new](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new) is one of those C++ language features that require an appropriate header to be included before one can even attempt to use them.

When using placement new, the expression must call an overload of `operator new` as part of its evaluation. *This* overload, to be exact:

```
void* operator new (std::size, void*);
```

But this function is not automatically declared for you in every translation unit. So to pull it in, you must include the correct header (`<new>`).

---

As a side note, that code you showed is very broken. It constructs the members of `myStruct` **twice**! Which for non-trivial cases could wreck havoc.

The proper way to very explicitly initialize `myStruct` is like this:

```
MyStruct myStruct {
  {}, // Default construct classA
  {}  // Default construct classB
};
```

Comment: Good answer - Side note; the explict initialisation isn't even required;  the default constructor on it's own will leave the object in the same state -  for this example.

Comment: @UKMonkey - That's true. Hence my quip about this being ***very** explicitly* initialized :)